# Anyone can support me how to select max value of column in sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I've written this code to project but it's not working, I want get max value of column version in db.PartPrice:

```
return db.JobPartMaster.findAll({
        where: filters,
        include: [{
            model: db.PartMaster,
            include: [{
                model: db.PartPrice.max('version',{
                include: [{
                    model: db.PartPriceDetail,
                }]})
            },
            {
                model: db.PDCategory,
            }]
        },
        {
            model: db.JobMaster,
        }]
    });
```

Can anybody spot the mistake?

Comment: You should include the error you get or the expected result

Comment: thank you, this is result:
"TypeError: self.$expandAttributes is not a function
I guess model: db.PartPrice.max('version') is problem, its not work